# Ajax call with a failed to load resource: the server response with a status 500 (internal server error)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I created a function that do an ajax call but I have this error when I call it.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

This is the code :

```
 $('#Item').change(function () {
        debugger
        $('#Price').empty();
        $('#Description').empty();
        $('#Quantity').val("");
        $('#Amount').val("");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Payments/GetItemByIdForEdit/",
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { id: $('#Item').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger

                $("#Price").val(data.ItemUnitPrice);
                $("#Description").val(data.itemDescription);
                //$("#productId").text(value.Id);



            }
        });
    });
```

this is the action code :

```
public JsonResult GetItemByIdForEdit(string id)
    {
        if (id != "")
        {
            int productId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            var product = _unitOfWork.Items.GetItemSingleOrDefault(productId);
            return Json(product, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            var product = new Item();
            //product.Description = "";
            //product.UnitPrice = 0.0;
            return Json(product, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
```

I don't see where is the problem ?

Do you have any solutions ?

thank you

this is the debugger mode result:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you go to that URL with a browser?

Comment: Go to to this action `public JsonResult GetItemByIdForEdit(string id)` then after fire this function,  success  function dose not fire  `success: function (data) {
                debugger

                $("#Price").val(data.ItemUnitPrice);
                $("#Description").val(data.itemDescription);
                //$("#productId").text(value.Id);



            }`  and gives me that error

Comment: the main problem for success function dose not fire after calling `GetItemByIdForEdit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing null value to controller. You have to stringify your paremater first. Example:

```
    var postData = JSON.stringify({
        'id': $('#Item').val()
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Payments/GetItemByIdForEdit/",
        datatype: "application/json",
        data: postData,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger

            $("#Price").val(data.ItemUnitPrice);
            $("#Description").val(data.itemDescription);
            //$("#productId").text(value.Id);



        }
    });
```

In your method you can use int directly

```
public JsonResult GetItemByIdForEdit(int id)
```

Comment: still the same issue  , in this method `public JsonResult GetItemByIdForEdit(int id)` the `id` is null after trying your solution

Comment: Are sure your Item has value? For example log it via console.log($('#Item').val())

Comment: Check my answer you have wrong jquery code. Postdata is not parameter its variable.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 code would normally indicate an error on the server, not anything with your code. Some thoughts

Talk to the server developer for more info. You can't get more info directly.
Verify your arguments into the call (values). Look for anything you might think could cause a problem for the server process. The process should not die and should return you a better code, but bugs happen there also.
Could be intermittent, like if the server database goes down. May be worth trying at another time.

Answer (score 0):

One of same problem's solition is dublicate post url. Change post URL and try again.